# Raspberry Turning on without really powering up. How?

Tags: pi-3, power, usb-power

My raspberry pi was trying to turn itself on without really powering up by USB cable. Although I am giving 12 volts to L298N shield from battery. I am making wireless RC car. When I give 5 volts from pin 2 of pi to the 5v port of shield, it is forcing pi to turn on. but why? because when i don't give volts from pi to shield, my wireless RC car still perfectly works. Please tell me what is this 5volt port in shield for plus tell me why my pi is turning on. I tried the same connections on l23d ic and car doesn't work if i don't give 5 volts from pi to IC. Why?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the standard design of the L298N motor driver board it can derive the 5V logic supply from the motor power supply.

You have two choices.

1. Don't connect a Pi 5V pin to logic supply 5V and leave the logic power jumper in place on the motor driver board.
2. Connect a Pi 5V pin to logic supply 5V and remove the logic power jumper from the motor driver board.

[image: L298N Motor Driver Module]